# how to merge object/string array in django-python?

Tags: python, django, arrays

I have a code in my django that it look like this:

```
firstname = ['Mark', 'Kate']
lastname = ['Brown', 'White']
```

and the out-put should be like this

```
person = [['Mark', 'Brown']
           ['Kate', 'White']]
```

can anyone can give me some hint or sample code on how to get the output?
i try to use this method:

```
person = firstname + lastname
```

but the output is :

```
['Mark', 'Kate', 'Brown', 'White']
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:
    `zip(firstname, lastmane)`